# How do Mnemonics work with Radio Buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I was expecting that when I use Alt+mnemonic that the related radio button would become focused and selected. My expectations are based on my knowledge of how mnemonics work in Swing. Are my expectation wrong?

In my example code below I set the number of each radio button to be the mnemonic.

1. "Option 1" is selected when the program starts.
2. When I use Alt+3, the program beeps at me, all the mnemonics become underlined and "Option 3" becomes focused but NOT selected. The GUI now looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip3om.png]

3. If I just type 2, "Option 2 becomes focused, but NOT selected.

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;

import javafx.event.*;

public class RadioButtonSSCCE extends Application
{
    public Parent createScene()
    {
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton( "Option _1" );
        rb1.setUserData("Option 1 selected");
        rb1.setToggleGroup( group );

        RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton( "Option _2" );
        rb2.setUserData("Option 2 selected");
        rb2.setToggleGroup( group );

        RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton( "Option _3" );
        rb3.setUserData("Option 3 selected");
        rb3.setToggleGroup( group );

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(rb1, rb2, rb3);

        ChangeListener<Toggle> cl = new ChangeListener<Toggle>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle)
            {
                if (group.getSelectedToggle() != null)
                {
                    String text = group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString();
                    System.out.println( text );
                }
            }
        };
        group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(cl);

        rb1.setSelected( true );

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createScene(), 125, 125);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Radio Button SSCCE");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have found that in order to invoke the mnemonic I have to:

1. press and release the Alt key. Now the mnemonic of each radio button is underlined.
2. press the number and the radio button becomes focused. However, I now need to use the space bar to select the radio button.

Why do I need to press the space bar? Should the radio button not be selected when the mnemonic is pressed?

Also, why can't I just use Alt+mnemonic as a single key combination to select a radio button?

Is my code wrong?

Edit:

The action is the key to selecting the radio button. I created a generic action to be shared by all buttons:

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> onAction = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        RadioButton button = (RadioButton)e.getSource();
        button.setSelected(true);
    }
};

rb1.setOnAction( onAction );
rb2.setOnAction( onAction );
rb3.setOnAction( onAction );
```

Since the radio buttons are part of a button group I didn't want the ability to unselect a button.

Comment: You've gone to the dark side it seems. ;)

Comment: It seems as though the mnemonics cause action events to be fired on the radio buttons, but that doesn't actually force the selection to change (I can't test directly, because it doesn't seem to recognise anything on my mac as "Alt"). That doesn't seem to cause selection to change though... that may be a bug.

Comment: @James_D It acts that way in JavaFX 2.2 and JavaFX 8, so it seems to be the intention. `CheckBox` works the same way.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yes, I decided to upgrade to Java 8 and see what JavaFX can do.

Comment: And... what's your take on it so far?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, basically I've just looked at the `Getting Started With JavaFX` tutorial from the [JavaFX Tutorial Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm). I feel a bit lost. It seems like there are more than one way to do everything. Simple things like setting colors and fonts. There are methods on the controls and now you can also use CSS and externalize all of this. There are all kinds of painting effects, shadows, rotations etc. As with anything the more flexible it is to use, the more powerful it can be, but the learning curve is also greater.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've been debating the plunge as well, either this, or just go the JS/CSS3/HTML5 route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Mnemonic` in JavaFX fires an [ActionEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Mnemonic.html#fire()) targeted at the registered `Node`. In the case of `RadioButton`, the ActionEvent doesn't toggle selection. You can add a generic handler to the `RadioButton` to toggle on the ActionEvent like this (assuming this is JavaFX 8).

```
rb1.setOnAction(event -> rb1.setSelected(!rb1.isSelected()));
```

Comment: Thanks. `In the case of RadioButton, the ActionEvent doesn't toggle selection.` - seems like a "missing feature" to me. When I use a mnemonic on a `Menu`, the menu pops up without any additional code. Also, any idea why I have to use two key strokes? 1) press/release Alt to paint the mnemonic character underlined 2) press the mnemonic character to invoke the Action. This goes against anything I've ever done before in a pure Windows app or a Swing app on Windows. Why can't I use Alt+mnemonic is one key stroke, without my computer beeping at me?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is a great solution for you. Continued testing is showing me that clicking on the `RadioButton` is not accurately selecting it. As far as the mnemonic key combination issue, I don't experience that. I can trigger the action using Alt+1 in a combined stroke. However, the mnemonic underline does remain on screen after the trigger.

Comment: The solution worked fine for me. In my action I just always made the radio button selected and I don't notice any problem, it is always selected and focused. The action does get triggered when I use Alt+1 (and the mnemonic stays underlined), but I also get a beeping sound like an error is made. Like in a Swing app and you use the Delete key on an empty JTextField (an empty JavaFX TextField does not make this sound). Wonder if it is a platform issue. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Do you get the beeping sound when trying to invoke other mnemonics (e.g. Alt+s)?  The [Windows OS will intercept and handle many keyboard shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8).  Just wondering if the beeping is due to something in the underlying OS rather than JavaFX.  Though Alt+1 is not in the published list from Microsoft that I can see, so I guess that is probably not your issue.  I can't test this because I don't have access to a Windows machine.

Comment: @jewelsea, Alt+F4, which close the frame works fine. But all the letter/number keys cause a beep whether a mnemonic is defined or not.

Comment: I tried pressing Alt+<numeric key> in a JavaFX application on OS X 10.9.5 and did not receive a beep.  I was using the numeric keys at the top of the keypad, not one in a separate numeric keypad (as I don't have one of those).  I'm guessing it is only JavaFX applications running under Windows which beep like this for you - which would seem to be a strange behavior you could report at http://bugreport.java.com.

Comment: @camickr: have you find a solutions to avoid beeps when the mnemonic is used?

Comment: @AnnieW., sorry, I don't know of a solution.

Answer (score 3):

As OttPrime notes in his answer and in the [Mnemonic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/Mnemonic.html) Javadoc:

> When a `Mnemonic` is registered on a `Scene`, and the `KeyCombination` reaches the `Scene` unconsumed, then the target `Node` will be sent an `ActionEvent`.

Now I think this is kind of an issue, because you don't really want to have only an [`ActionEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/ActionEvent.html) sent to the radio button, instead you want to [`fire()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/RadioButton.html#fire--) the radio button.

> Toggles the state of the radio button if and only if the RadioButton has not already selected or is not part of a ToggleGroup.

Note: firing a radio button will also send an `ActionEvent` to the button.

Here is the Java 8u40 code for `Button::fire`

```
@Override public void fire() {
    if (!isDisabled()) {
        fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `ToggleButton::fire`

```
@Override public void fire() {
    // TODO (aruiz): if (!isReadOnly(isSelected()) {
    if (!isDisabled()) {
        setSelected(!isSelected());
        fireEvent(new ActionEvent());
    }
}
```

And here is the code for `RadioButton::fire`

```
@Override public void fire() {
    // we don't toggle from selected to not selected if part of a group
    if (getToggleGroup() == null || !isSelected()) {
        super.fire();
    }
}
```

Note: RadioButton is a ToggleButton, so the super.fire() call will invoke the ToggleButton fire() code.

So, a mnemonic for a button will be fine: All the mnemonic is doing is sending an ActionEvent to the button (which is exactly the same as the fire implementation for the button).  However, ToggleButtons and RadioButtons do extra stuff in their fire methods for manipulating the selection state of the ToggleButton, so mnemonic invocations aren't going to do that.

Now, you might say, well that's OK, I'll just implement OttPrime's workaround:

```
rb1.setOnAction(event -> rb1.setSelected(!rb1.isSelected()));
```

This will be great when you select the button via a mnemonic, but (as far as I can see), it will break other functionality for button selection (for example, if you programmatically fire the radio button and, probably, also if you click on the radio button with a mouse).  This is because the selection state of the button will change twice (once in the fire() code and again in your action code) and you probably don't want that.  Unfortunately, I can't actually test this theory as I don't have access to a machine which can use mnemonics.

So, to answer your original question "How do Mnemonics work with Radio Buttons"? => They don't (at least in IMO, not in any way that really makes sense).

I'd advise just [disabling Mnemonic parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setMnemonicParsing-boolean-) for radio buttons and toggle buttons.

Comment: The code I posted in my edit, just uses setSelected(true). Since I'm using my radio buttons in a group, I just want to select the button with the mnemonic. It appears to work using this approach, or using the fire() method. However, I did further testing (based on your comments). When a button does not belong to a toggle group there are problems when you start using the mouse. Sometimes the button stays at the same state, and sometimes I get an Exception. I agree it doesn't work the way I would expect. (+1)

Comment: Do you happen to know how clicking the radio button with the mouse changes the state of the button? Its not important, I just started playing with JavaFX and am curious. I tried looking at the source but I can't see how events are handled. If you know the class to look at it would be great.

Comment: I agree that this is the more correct solution in general. I noticed the mouse click issue after I had posted my answer.